# Behavior of IE for ReadOnly TextArea, while hit enter key

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have one ReadOnly TextArea, some buttons, some input controls like text, radio buttons, dropdowns etc. I am taking focus to the ReadOnly TextArea and hit the enter key. As a result, the focus goes to the very first button of the page and executes its Click event. I am using Windows 7 and IE 9. Is that the IE behavior? Please refer to any documentation on that and the solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the IE behaviour. The first button on your page is the default button on the page, which will get clicked once you press Enter from an input field. You can set the default button for your form using its `DefaultButton` property.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to mention, the same is not happening in Firefox. That is why I feel, its IE behavior.